# Visual Studio "Find in Files" RegEx behaving unexpectedly

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to write a RegEx to find all strings that contain at least one lowercase character.

Here is what I have: `"(\\"|[^"]|"")*?[a-z](\\"|[^"]|"")*?"`

While it's not perfect and will match stuff it shouldn't, my real problem is that it also matches uppercase-only strings. Strangely, when I use "Quick find" within the file it works. In both cases I have the "Match case" option enabled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you provide a ex?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason why "Find in Files" and "Quick Find" behave differently: With "Quick Find" character classes like `[^"]` or `[\s\S]` don't match line breaks (this is unexpected) while with "Find in Files" they do.

The problem with my RegEx is that it also matches "inverse strings". So if I have `Foo("TEST").Bar("TEST")` it will match `").Bar("`

To improve this behavior (still far from perfect) this RegEx can be used: `(?<![\w\.\)\\"])"(\\"|[^"]|"")*?[a-z](\\"|[^"]|"")*?"`